# Is there a function mapping x to the nearest multiple of a given value with cleaner coding than my 'classify'?

Tags: r, cut

My function is built on very basic elements, I wonder if there are more general and direct solutions.

```r
# function mapping x to the nearest multiple of a given value 
#          with lower_limit included (or excluded if right = TRUE)
classify <- function(x, class_width, right = FALSE) 
  if (right) 
    ceiling(ceiling(x-class_width/2)/class_width)*class_width else
      floor(floor(  x+class_width/2)/class_width)*class_width

cw <- 3
z <- c(c(-.5, 0, .5)+cw/2)
z <- c(z, z + cw)
z <- sort(c(-z, z))
cbind(z, cls_left = classify(z, cw), cls_right = classify(z, cw, T))
#>          z cls_left cls_right
#>  [1,] -5.0       -6        -6
#>  [2,] -4.5       -3        -6
#>  [3,] -4.0       -3        -3
#>  [4,] -2.0       -3        -3
#>  [5,] -1.5        0        -3
#>  [6,] -1.0        0         0
#>  [7,]  1.0        0         0
#>  [8,]  1.5        3         0
#>  [9,]  2.0        3         3
#> [10,]  4.0        3         3
#> [11,]  4.5        6         3
#> [12,]  5.0        6         6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>